# If..else is nested in while loop with oci and php, but if...else is not called

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to use if..else in a while loop. However, the script in else{ echo " " ;} was not called when the variable $objParse returns 0 rows, but the script was called when returns the rows. Could anybody help me out? Thanks a lot!

```
<?php
while($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse, OCI_BOTH)) {
    if (oci_num_rows ($objParse)) {
        echo "yes";
    } else {
        echo "No";
    }
    ?>
    <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=&#39;#C0C0C0&#39;;this.style.cursor=&#39;pointer&#39;;" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=&#39;#FFFFFF&#39;;">
        <td>
            <div align="center">
                <a href="http://s****/query/sr.php?CusID=<?=$objResult["FIELDBOOK"];?>"><font size="2.95"><b><?=$objResult["FIELDBOOK"];?></b></font>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div align="center"><?=$objResult["PROJECT"];?></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div align="center"><?=$objResult["DEPT"];?></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div align="center"><?=$objResult["COMMUNITY"];?></div>
        </td>  
        <td>
            <div align="center"><?=$objResult["CORTE"];?></div>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><?=$objResult["PMB"];?></td>
        <td align="center"><?=$objResult["PME"];?></td>
        <td align="center"><?=$objResult["TYPE"];?></td>
        <td align="center"><?=$objResult["AREA"];?></td>
        <td align="center"><?=$objResult["OFFICESUPERVISOR"];?></td>
        <td align="center">
            <a href=http://10.56.12.59/surveys/notes/<?=$objResult["YEAR"];?>/<?=$objResult["FIELDBOOK"];?>><font size="2.8">View Folder</font></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
oci_close($objConnect);
```

?>

Comment: while(($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse, OCI_BOTH)) != false) { var_dump($objResult); echo "ok"; } you don't need to use if else statements

Comment: I'd avoid the internal overhead of constructing numeric & associative result arrays caused by using `OCI_BOTH`.  Just use `OCI_ASSOC`  in your case.

Answer (score 3):

To put it simple: The while loop did never run. If you get 0 results, an empty array/row or false is returned and [in php an empty array evaluates to false](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

Comment: Also I edited your html sintax, you are missing closing div tags, be carefull with that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know how can I echo "Record Not Found " if it returns 0 rows in a while loop statement since as you mentioned, only when it returns rows, the "While" loop statement will keep running the script.

Comment: Add a counter variable, initialize it with 0 and increment it inside the while loop. `$rowIndex = 0; while (<condition>) { doSomething(); $rowIndex++; } $rowCount = $rowIndex; echo $rowCount;`